# emacs hg remove function

Tags: emacs, mercurial

Is there an emacs command for `hg remove` in the VC mode? I've scoured the emacs manual but can only find `vc-delete-file`.

`C-x v v` handles `hg add` and `hg commit` based on context of the file but I can't see how you can remove a file once added (from within emacs)

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Mercurial, so I can't comment further, but I note that `vc-hg.el` contains the following commented function:

```lisp
;; FIXME: This would remove the file. Is that correct?
;; (defun vc-hg-unregister (file)
;;   "Unregister FILE from hg."
;;   (vc-hg-command nil nil file "remove"))
```

as well as:

```lisp
;; Modeled after the similar function in vc-bzr.el
(defun vc-hg-delete-file (file)
  "Delete FILE and delete it in the hg repository."
  (condition-case ()
      (delete-file file)
    (file-error nil))
  (vc-hg-command nil 0 file "remove" "--after" "--force"))
```

(the latter being what `vc-delete-file` is going to execute in this context)

Comment: I wonder why its commented out? I think its a reasonably common use-case to want to remove a file from a repo but not delete it all together

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps you could test it out on a disposable repository, and if it works as expected you could submit a bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) pointing out that the function works and is useful, and suggesting that it be uncommented in future versions.